# 2D NSString array usage inside block method

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, objective-c-blocks

Why am I not able to use this?

```
__block NSString *tableStrings[4][2];

[userValues enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *userScore, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        tableStrings[idx][0] = @"< 5";
        tableStrings[idx][1] = @"> 95";
}];
```

The compiler is yelling at me of `"Cannot refer to declaration with an array type inside block"`. I was under the impression that denoting `__block` before the variable would allow this to be done. I can make it work with using `NSString[x][x]` but I'm curious as to why this is not allowed.

Comment: try `NSString * __block  tableStrings[4][2];`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455592/access-c-array-within-blocks-variable-array-count-objective-c

Comment: None of those work, thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Blocks cannot access array variables of automatic or `__block` storage from the enclosing scope. That's just a restriction of blocks. It's because both of those things requires being able to copy the variable. And array type is not assignable.

It would be possible for them to make a special case for arrays, that arrays are copied element-by-element. C++11 lambdas makes this special case, so they can capture arrays by value, even though arrays are not assignable. However, the blocks people didn't bother to make this special case.