# Accessing a C array of blocks inside a block

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a C array of blocks defined like this:

```
void (^block1)() = ^void() {
  doSomething1();
  doSomething2();
};

void (^block2)() = ^void() {
  doSomething3();
  doSomething4();
};

// etc.
typedef void (^myBlockType)();
myBlockType arrayBlock[2];
arrayBlock[0] = block1;
arrayBlock[1] = block2;
```

but then I am trying to access that C array from inside a block, something like

```
void (^adjust)(int value) = ^void(int value) {
    myBlockType myBlock = arrayBlock[value];
};
```

and Xcode is whining with

> Cannot refer to declaration with an array type inside block

If this was an array of stuff like floats, integers, etc., there is [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5455740/316469) but how to do that for a C array of blocks?

Can I do

```
    myBlockType array = calloc(2, sizeof(myBlockType));
```

? Is this the correct approach? In that case how do I initialize the values?

Comment: Two questions (a) you don't say why you are not using an `NSArray`, that would be helpful to know (b) the linked *question* (not the *answer*) provides you with a solution - it has an array of X, you have an array of Y, makes no difference to procedure - so what about that didn't work for you? Might be best if you edit the question to answer (just leave a comment you've done so).

Comment: Sorry, my C sucks but I have to use a C array because the module I have to interact with, not written by me, is all written in C. Beyond the fact that my C sucks, my other problem is that that this other array is not accessible by using the syntax `array[i]`. I have tried it and Xcode whined all over the place. I guess that elements on that array has to be accessed using pointers and I don't have a clue on how to do that, or how even to fill that array with elements to start.

Comment: continued... and looking at the link with my poor knowledge of C does not make me see an answer there... if you can answer how I create that, populate and obtain the items, I will accept the answer... and yes, I know, my C stinks. Thanks

Comment: Seriously you need to learn some (more - Objective-C is a superset so you must know some) C if you are doing this. "my other problem is that that this other array is not accessible by using the syntax `array[i]`" - if you are importing a C array *or* pointer then this syntax *will work*. If "Xcode whined all over the place" then something is **wrong**. Figure out what (asking a question on SO if needed) before trying to move on.

Comment: this is why I have created this question. Lets hope someone knows how to do that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This question is not about that "other array" and Xcode whining. Solve that issue *before* this one is what I'm recommending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, some pointers after the comment trail, *but you need to learn and understand what is going on here*.

> Can I do
>
> ```
> myBlockType array = calloc(2, sizeof(myBlockType));
> ```

- In C arrays are pointers are closely interrelated. In the C array `T x[n]` the name `x` has type `T *` - a pointer. The index operation `x[n]` is defined to be the same as `*(x + n)` using pointer operations (`*` & `+`). So you can treat an array like a pointer and a pointer like an array, e.g. you can "index" a pointer.
- As you have discovered you cannot capture a *local* array variable in a block.
- You *can* capture a pointer-valued variable, **but** it is your responsibility to make sure what is pointed at remains valid.
- Your `calloc` idea is one possible solution, but the types are wrong, `array` needs to be declared as a pointer.
- Furthermore if you are using ARC (more than likely) and storing pointers of *retainable object type*, e.g. references to objects or blocks, then the type of `array` must include an *ownership qualifier*. You probably should use `__strong` so your "array" owns the items it references just as an `NSArray` does.
- For anything you `calloc` (or `malloc` *et al*) you are responsible for calling `free` if and when required.

Understand those bullets and your possible solutions (there is more than one) just fall out.

HTH